# sql query to sum and insert in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

As per the schema defined in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a3fa8/1) I want to get the sum of credits - sum of debits and then insert this for each customer number is another table as customer number, balance. any clues how to do it, I tried the query in the fiddle but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you've confused `ACCOUNT_TYPE` and `TRANSACTION_TYPE` in your ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS table - you put the transaction types (credit, debit) in the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` field, and you put the account types (customer, etc) in the `TRANSACTION_TYPE` field.

If you switch the ACCOUNT_TYPE and TRANSACTION_TYPE fields in your table definition you get:

```
create table account_transactions
  (customer_number varchar2(10),
   transaction_type varchar2(10),
   account_type varchar2(10),
   amount number);

insert into account_transactions values('5555','credit','customer',10);
insert into account_transactions values('5555','debit','customer',10);
insert into account_transactions values('5555','debit','other',15);
insert into account_transactions values('5555','credit','mgr',15);
```

[Here's a fiddle with the fields flipped around](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5aeaa1/1)

With the table populated correctly your query

```
SELECT t1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER, sum(t2.amount - t1.amount) AS balance
  FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS t1,
       ACCOUNT_TRANSACTIONS t2
  where t1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER=t2.CUSTOMER_NUMBER and 
        t1.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'debit' AND
        t2.TRANSACTION_TYPE= 'credit' and
        t1.ACCOUNT_TYPE='customer' and
        t2.ACCOUNT_TYPE='customer'
  GROUP BY t1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

works fine.

Best of luck.

Comment: what if there are multiple such transactions (credit,debit) the result gives incorrect value for sum(). If I execute individual query for credit,debit I get correct values

Comment: I suggest  you ask another question about that. Include the data to reproduce the problem you describe and your query which demonstrates the problem. Include a reference to this question in your new question. Thanks.